# How to get the names of songs in a directory using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is a directory in my server where there are lots of mp3 and ogg files. And there is a player in my site that gets an array of those songs in that directory and play them. The array should be defined like this:

```
[ 'song1', 'song2', 'song3', 'songx' ]
```

How can I get the name of those songs like this array using javascript in my template?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: Nothing yet to get the names as array automatically. Just the directory is defined and by writing songs name as array, player starts playing. But we need this work to be done automatically, because each user in site has his own directory with special songs names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to get file names from client side you must use nodejs 
this code can be helpful

```
function walkSync(currentDirPath, callback) {
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');
fs.readdirSync(currentDirPath).forEach(function (name) {
    var filePath = path.join(currentDirPath, name);
    var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
    if (stat.isFile()) {
        callback(filePath, stat);
    } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        walkSync(filePath, callback);
    }
});}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the scenario is that this is player in each member's profile page. So, each member can upload as many mp3 files as they want. Each member's files will be stored in a dedicated folder with his own username in server. File path to each folder is defined in template. Just a short part remains that will show an array of files in that directory. As you see, if I write the names as hard coded, then it starts playing, but I want to get the files names automatically. Just need a block of code to replace with that array to get the names from a pre-defined directory and show them as array.

Comment: I don't understand - That person wrote you a great answer (+1) for your very low low quality question. Was it so hard to include this details in the original post, rather than let him waste their time?

Comment: My bad. Mehran's answer seems to be what I was looking for. Just was hard for me to get it work, because of my weakness in js. Thanks